# Cerrado por demasiado amplio usado para preguntas de baja calidad

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Según el centro de ayuda, cerrado por demasiado amplio significa:

> Muy amplia - Si tu pregunta puede ser respondida por un libro entero, o tiene muchas respuestas válidas, probablemente es muy extensa para nuestro formato.
>
> > Existen muchas respuestas posibles o buenas respuestas. Pueden ser muy extensas para este formato. Por favor agrega detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o para isolar un problema que puede ser respondido en pocos párrafos.

Y veo usos correctos de ese cierre como:
[Como hacer un calendario en PHP mostrando todos los meses con días deshabilitados [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64853/como-hacer-un-calendario-en-php-mostrando-todos-los-meses-con-d%C3%ADas-deshabilitado)

Pero me da la impresión de que, en algunos casos, se está usando con este significado:

> La pregunta es de baja calidad.

Por ejemplo:

[Crear un algoritmo en python [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64865/crear-un-algoritmo-en-python)
[Duda con Python-Django [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64424/duda-con-python-django)
[Cómo obtener el usuario actual de Windows desde Java [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64653/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-el-usuario-actual-de-windows-desde-java)

O peor aún, buenas preguntas:
[Agregar información al EXIF de una imagen [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53375/agregar-informaci%C3%B3n-al-exif-de-una-imagen)

## ¿Son demasiado amplias?

Podría argumentarse que cada una de las preguntas anteriores admiten infinitas respuestas, pero también admiten infinitas respuestas estas: [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62085/pasar-el-contendido-de-un-objeto-a-may%C3%BAsculas) y [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58142/obtener-el-valor-de-una-promesa)

Por demasiado amplia yo entiendo una pregunta que requiere de respuestas muy extensas. O que se puede hacer con decenas de herramientas distintas y lo más probable es que una respuesta, aunque correcta, no sirva al autor; salvo en caso de afortunada casualidad.

Este es el caso de la pregunta del calendario, que da para muchas subpreguntas.

Pero desde luego no es para la del algoritmo en Python que es un poco más complejo que un hola mundo:

```python
try:
    nums=int(raw_input('Cuantos numeros?:'))
    total = 0
    for n in range(1, nums+1):
        val=int(raw_input("  Valor " + str(n) + " :"))
        total += val 
    print( "El total es " + str(total) )

except ValueError:
    print "Eso no es un numero"
```

## ¿Es correcto cerrar por demasiado amplia una pregunta que no es demasiado amplia pero sí es de baja calidad?

Desde luego que no.

Esto perjudica al sitio pues los usuarios que ven esas preguntas cerradas pueden acabar pensando que ese tipo de preguntas no son apropiadas para el sitio (cuando sí lo son) y que no vale la pena esforzarse en redactar la pregunta mejor, poniendo un buen ejemplo de código, porque por muy bien que la redacten va a ser rechazada dado que es muy amplia.
O si conocen el sitio comprenderán que la moderación es mala pues, se cierra erróneamente.

## ¿Qué se debe hacer ante una pregunta que no entra en ningún motivo de cierre pero que no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil?

Votar negativo. No cerrar.
Alternativamente : Votar Negativo. Cierre: **No relacionado->Otro->No parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil**.

Comment: Es una buena interpretación. Tan buena como cualquier otra. La alternativa que propones es igualmente muy respetable. Gracias por compartir tu opinión.

Comment: @toledano No es tan buena como cualquier otra. Cerrar sin respetar lo que indica el centro de ayuda respecto a los motivos de cierre es PEOR que actuar respetando esos criterios.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que tu interpretación __es la única correcta__? Estoy seguro que tienes razón, aunque tal vez me tome tiempo llevar a cabo este cambio, te aseguro que lo tendré en cuenta cada vez que vea una pregunta con estas características. Gracias, de nuevo, por tu tiempo.

Comment: ¿Has considerado las otras opciones de cierre? Por ejemplo "No está claro lo que se pregunta", o bien "no relacionado porque... > Otro (añade un comentario explicando cuál es el problema)" . También cabría mencionar, que si bien los que votaron para cierre pudieron seleccionar cada uno motivos diferentes, sólo se mostrará un motivo. Por otro lado, se podría destacar que algunas preguntas se eliminan de forma automática luego de un tiempo", por ejemplo, las que no tienen respuestas y tienen votos negativos.

Comment: @toledano No. Sí quiero decir que escribir un programa en python que sume unos números no es demasiado amplio. Lo mismo respecto al usuario de Windows en Java. At Ruben la pregunta de EXIF ¿qué motivo de cierre merece? Es una pregunta sobre un tema muy concreto y que pone código completo y breve. --- Este esfuerzo por limpiar la "basura" del sitio es loable pero cerrar buenas preguntas, o cerrar preguntas que merecen un negativo en vez de un cierre no es bueno; perjudica más que ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece muy interesante la reflexión que haces a este respecto. Haciendo el símil de las penas de prisión, podemos ver la finalidad de cerrar una pregunta de dos maneras: con función de ***rehabilitar*** y con función de ***castigar***.

La función de *castigar* tiene su sentido en tanto en cuanto tenemos unas líneas sobre qué queremos, por lo que se salga de allí lo consideramos nocivo para el sitio. Preguntas del tipo "hazme los deberes" no las queremos, así que las *castigamos* cerrándolas.

Sin embargo, lo que finalmente quiere la comunidad es que el conocimiento fluya y, principalmente, ayudar a las personas. De ahí que exista la función *rehabilitadora* al cerrar una pregunta: te decimos que así como está, no tiene cabida en nuestro sitio; pero además, te indicamos qué ha fallado para que puedas editar tu publicación, hacer que sea reabierta y conseguir respuestas interesantes.

Para rehabilitar, pues, hay que saber de qué se le acusa. Si te acusan de posesión de armas pero lo que cometiste es fraude fiscal, es más difícil que mejores tu conducta.

Por tanto, estoy absolutamente de acuerdo en que se seleccione el motivo exacto para que el usuario reciba toda la información necesaria.

Sin embargo, cuando comentas:

> #### ¿Qué se debe hacer ante una pregunta que no entra en ningún motivo de cierre pero que no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil?
>
> Votar negativo. No cerrar.

Allí no estoy de acuerdo en lo de "No cerrar" (y sí en lo de "Votar negativo"). Si la pregunta en líneas generales va en contra de lo indicado en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) o cae dentro lo dicho en *Algunas preguntas no son pertinentes incluso si encajan con una de las categorías mencionadas anteriormente* de esa página, entonces hay que cerrarla. ¿Pero y si no hay ningún motivo específico para cerrarla? Pues tal y como [se sugiere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255341/1983854) por allí, o bien indica "no está claro lo que se pregunta" o bien selecciona "otro" en "No relacionado" y explica brevemente el motivo por el que se debería cerrar.

Comment: Me alegra ver que no soy el único que piensa que no se debe cerrar por demasiado amplio una pregunta de baja calidad. Pero me sorprende que se use dos herramientas para rechazar una pregunta, el cierre y el voto. Podría parecer más razonable usar solo una (menos esfuerzo) o usarlas para fines distintos (menos confusión). La alternativa de usar "No relacionado->Otro->Baja Calidad" es la menos mala de todas cuando cierras algo por ser de baja calidad, pero sigue sin ser la mejor pues se marca como No Relacionada una pregunta que sí está relacionada.

Comment: Y añadir que en la respuesta de meta en inglés que enlazas dicen "In the first instance bad questions should be down-voted." Totalmente de acuerdo. Obsérvese que con frecuencia no es el caso aquí, en que se cierra una pregunta con cero votos negativos. Y más importante : **"Secondly, if you really think a bad question should be closed, then"** que interpreto como que realmente no hace falta cerrarlas solo por ser malas pero que si **realmente** quieres cerrarla al menos lo hagas por el motivo correcto.

Comment: @Jose probablemente la clave reside en recopilar este tipo de preguntas y ver si hay algún patrón que se repite en exceso. En tal caso, plantear que se añada un nuevo tipo de motivo de cierre. Actualmente solo tenemos dos propios: "está en inglés" y "error tipográfico o no reproducible". En [so] tienen "pertenece a [su]", "pertenece a [sf]", "pide recomendación de libro o software", "es del tipo ¿por qué no funciona mi código?" y "error tipográfico o no reproducible". Por tanto, lo más lógico parece luchar por conseguir que alguna de estas puedan incluirse aquí.

Answer (score 7):

Estoy convencido que antes de votar (de forma positiva o negativa) y sobre todo antes de proponer una pregunta para cierre o votar para cerrar una pregunta se debe analizar y elegir la mejor opción **para cada caso**. Es decir, debe ser una *decisión **casuística***.

También estoy convencido que **las herramientas de moderación funcionan**. Es decir que *debemos confiar* en el criterio y la opinión de las personas que hacen las tareas de revisión.

Sin embargo, las herramientas de moderación, pese a que se necesitan cinco opiniones para cerrar una pregunta, no son infalibles, pero sin duda reducen el riesgo de falso negativos. Dicho en otras palabras, **podemos equivocarnos**, ya al elegir la causa de cierre, ya al votar en uno u otro sentido, ya al decidir no actuar ante decisión de moderación.

Es mi convicción personal que llamar *"buena pregunta"* a una publicación es una cuestión personalísima. Creo que en la gran mayoría de los casos, todos coincidimos en lo que es una "buena pregunta", aunque no podamos precisar los detalles que la conforman. Para eso son las políticas y las guías. Pero estas políticas y guías están sujetas a las interpretaciones personales.

#### Conclusión

Creo que debemos asumir el riesgo de una mala decisión, porque es mínimo.

Creo que si sigues buscando, vas a encontrar mas preguntas, que en tu opinión hayan sido mal cerradas o tengan una causa de cierre incorrectas.

Entre más tiempo le dediques a esta actividad, más "malas decisiones" vas a encontrar y tu opinión en este sentido se va a reforzar.

Te invito a que confíes en el sistema de moderación. Sé que no es perfecto, pero es el único que tenemos. Yo sé que es muy desafortunado cuando el sistema falla, pero sé muy bien que en la gran mayoría de los casos funciona.

La experiencia en la moderación es colectiva y esfuerzos como el tuyo, nos ayudan a mejorar a todos. Hacen que frenemos un poco y razonemos un poco más al decidir.

Por mi parte, yo prefiero votar negativo las respuestas, meas que las preguntas, pero te aseguro que me tomaré mi tiempo para aclarar los motivos de proponer un cierre y usar menos, en la medida de lo posible, el tan genérico *"demasiado amplia"*.

Espero que tu propuesta tenga todo el éxito.

Comment: La confianza es para quien desconoce. Por ejemplo al abrir la beta, no conoces a la gente y decides dar un voto de confianza a quien modera. Yo ya lo hice. Pasado todo este tiempo he podido ver con mucha frecuencia un uso incorrecto de las herramientas de moderación (las cuales sí funcionan, el problema está en algunos de los que las usan). Hace falta una herramienta que modere a los moderadores, de tal forma que quien abusa del privilegio lo pierda. De tal forma que un voto de cierre no se use como un negativo (pero que no hace bajar mi reputación). Review audits se llaman en inglés.

Comment: +1 esta respuesta es útil. Que no esté de acuerdo no significa que no sea útil.

Comment: En mi experiencia como auditor de procesos bajo la norma ISO 9001, la confianza es un valor objetivo y mensurable que indica el grado de seguridad de que un sistema se va a comportar de la forma esperada, es decir, que bajo condiciones iguales produce resultados dentro de los limites establecidos.